# Warining "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.49911e-34FALSE" when running zeroinfl()

Tags: generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

I am using the `pscl` package to run a zero inflated estimation, however when I do I get the following warning:

```
zeroinfl(count ~ origin + type, data = glm_df, dist = "poisson")
    Warning message:
    In value[[3L]](cond) :
      system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.49911e-34FALSE
```

From reading around it indicates either my design matrix can't be inverted (but I am not really sure what that means), but it is caused by covariance of my variables? Or my data is not able to support the model.

What does this mean and indicate and how can I debug it?

Comment: This is a common confusion that has been asked many times in slightly different ways. Try [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=system+is+computationally+singular) & read some of the related threads.

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you for this. As I stated I had read around but had not found a solution that fit my question. Most other people are presenting errors whilst mine is a warning. Secondly mine is on a zero inflated model of which few other people asking about this seem to be.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: @RMM, whether you are fitting a zero inflated model or other type of model is unrelated to what it means for the condition number to be approximately / exactly 0. Moreover, whether the function throws an error or lists a warning is mostly about how the function was coded. Lastly, be aware that questions about software usage (eg, code, warnings & error messages) are typically considered to be off topic here, so this is a fine needle to thread (for instance, note that the duplicate is closed as *off topic*).

Comment: Apologies, I posted it here as I have noticed others with similar questions that had not been marked as such.  Would my first step to debugging this be to check for covariance between column of my dataset? Note this is count data so all parameter columns are just categorical character variables, if that changes anything?

Comment: @RMM, no need to apologize. (Be aware, if you want me to see your comment, you need to ping me by including `@gung` in your comment.) These being *count* data only necessarily applies to your response variable (here `count`, I gather). The variables you are concerned about are the RHS variables, `origin` & `type`. Those are collinear (read some of our threads on [tag:multicollinearity]). If they are categorical, try making a table (in R: `with(glm_df, table(origin, type))`).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica so from my understanding after reading, type origin or sample are collinear, I would maybe assume sample and origin as they are in effect nested, as origin refers to the origin of the sample (free living or associated with my experiment). From further reading it seems this is not inherently a problem with the predictive power of my model but maybe makes it over fitted to the sample data? SO do i have the choice to continue and ignore the error (I am not getting it when I using a normal glm)?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Secondly, when I look at the zero inflated models coefficient, one of the `origin` labels is not being shown, I think this is as it is being taken as the intercept due to it being resented first in the model? However a variable of `type` is also not being shown. From reading around I get the impression this maybe be due to that variable only having one zero. But when looking at that variable this is not the case. Here is a subset of my data if that helps: https://pastebin.com/sDfcQMiJ.